# Make actor clip child Image

Tags: libgdx

I want an actor that draws a drawable, but clips it to the size of the actor. I'm deriving this class from Widget, and using some hard-coded values as a simple test:

```
public class MyWidget extends Widget {

    public MyWidget(Drawable drawable) {
        setDrawable(drawable);
        setSize(100, 100);
    }

    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        clipBegin(getX(), getY(), 20, 20);

        drawable.draw(batch, getX(), getY(), 500, 500);

        clipEnd();
    }
}
```

No clipping is performed though, the drawable spills out of the bounds of the actor. This actor is part of a Table, if it matters. I believe I am using the clipBegin() / clipEnd() methods incorrectly. What is the right way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure this is the problem, but `clipBegin` returns a boolean, and you should only invoke `clipEnd` if true is returned.  (The doc is pretty sparse, it implies you shouldn't invoke draw if clip returns false, too,  I think): http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html#clipBegin-float-float-float-float-

Comment: Did you ever figure out the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I found based on the comments and my own experimentation. It's important to flush the batch before starting the clip and after drawing to ensure the proper drawing gets clipped.

```
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    batch.flush();
    if (clipBegin(getX(), getY(), 20.0f, 20.0f)) {
        //do your drawing here
        drawable.draw(batch, getX(), getY(), 500, 500);
        batch.flush();
        clipEnd();
    }
}
```